# tensorflow rnn model path

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow

I have trained the language model using Tensorflow as given in thie [tutorial](http://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/recurrent/index.html)

For training I used the following command.

```
 bazel-bin/tensorflow/models/rnn/ptb/ptb_word_lm   --data_path=./simple-examples/data/  --model small
```

The training was successful with the following o/p at the end.

```
Epoch: 13 Train Perplexity: 37.196
Epoch: 13 Valid Perplexity: 124.502
Test Perplexity: 118.624
```

But I am still confused with, where the training model is stored and how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

The demo code probably did not include the ability to save a model; you might want to explicitly use `tf.train.Saver` to save and restore variables to and from checkpoints.

See [doc](http://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/state_ops.html#Saver) and [examples](http://www.tensorflow.org/how_tos/variables/index.html#saving-and-restoring).

It's pretty straightforward according to the doc. In below example, I saved
all the variables in the model. Instead, you can choose which variable(s) to save by following the [examples](http://www.tensorflow.org/how_tos/variables/index.html#saving-and-restoring).

```
# ... 
tf.initialize_all_variables().run()
####################################################
# Add ops to save and restore all the variables.
####################################################
saver = tf.train.Saver()

for i in range(config.max_max_epoch):
  lr_decay = config.lr_decay ** max(i - config.max_epoch, 0.0)
  m.assign_lr(session, config.learning_rate * lr_decay)

  print("Epoch: %d Learning rate: %.3f" % (i + 1, session.run(m.lr)))
  train_perplexity = run_epoch(session, m, train_data, m.train_op,
                               verbose=True)
  print("Epoch: %d Train Perplexity: %.3f" % (i + 1, train_perplexity))
  valid_perplexity = run_epoch(session, mvalid, valid_data, tf.no_op())
  print("Epoch: %d Valid Perplexity: %.3f" % (i + 1, valid_perplexity))

  ####################################################
  # Save the variables to disk.
  ####################################################
  save_path = saver.save(session, "/tmp/model.epoch.%03d.ckpt" % (i + 1))
  print("Model saved in file: %s" % save_path)
  # ....
```

In my case, each checkpoint file has a disk size of 18.61M (`--model small`).

Regarding how to use the model, just follow the [doc](http://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/state_ops.html#Saver) to restore the checkpoints from saved files. Then it's at your will how to use it.

Comment: Thanks :) for giving the hint. But I am a beginner, can you give some more explicit example of how to train and save the model with the code which complements with the demo model given in the tutorial.

Comment: Should the `sess` in `save_path = saver.save(sess, "/tmp/model.epoch.%03d.ckpt" % (i + 1))` be `session`, the same session aforementioned, as in `valid_perplexity = run_epoch(session, mvalid, valid_data, tf.no_op())` and others?